# using ssh and running a script in background

Tags: ssh

I am running a job that takes about 20 minutes in each server.  However, all the servers can run this job at the same time.  Here is my job:

```
#cat mylist

server1
server2
...
...

#for i in `mylist`; do ssh root@$i /home/run_command ; done
```

It works fine but it has to finish the job on each server before moving on to the next server.

I tried adding `&`

```
for i in `mylist`; do ssh root@$i /home/run_command & ; done
```

It did not make a difference.  I appreciate any information you can share with me.

Comment: Consider using dsh (distributed shell), ideal for this.

Comment: Another option would be to run each ssh in its own `screen` or `tmux`, especially if you expect some output from the command.

Comment: @steve `dsh` can do many things, and also what the OP asked for, but it is not installed by default, whereas ssh (which dsh needs) _is_ practically installed everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

You can tell `ssh` to go into the background with `-f` so doing something like

```
for i in $(cat mylist); do
    ssh -f root@$i /home/run_command
done
```

As Alex Stragies pointed out, this will let you enter passwords for hosts as needed, though if you have a long list hopefully you will be using public key authentication for your own sake.

Comment: This is the/a correct answer, but you may want to change the last phrase. The man page for my ssh states, that '-f' will allow the entry of passwords, and then go to background. This is also the recommended way to start X11 programs. 'ssh -f host xterm'.